# Finding top n numbers in a file

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to find an algo to find top n numbers in a file containing thousands of numbers.
Before that i checked finding top n numbers in an array but couldnt get a concrete solution.
Sorting is an obvious option but is there any other way? Maybe same logic can be applied to file

Comment: What tools can you use? How is the file organised?

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074463/most-suitable-sorting-algorithm

Comment: file is organised with numbers in random order...
I guess the prev post has the answer... variation of max heap sort shud be one of the soln

Comment: That's probably the best solution in this case. There are faster approaches, but they rely on having the whole file in memory; rob mayoff's solution only needs O(n) space to find the top n numbers, so it's better suited to reading inputs from a stream. But it might be overkill depending on what kind of scales we're dealing with here. How many numbers in your file, and how big is your "n"?

Answer (score 3):

If `f` is the number of numbers in the file, and `n` is the number you need to extract, you can do it in `O(n + f lg n)` (which actually is `O(f lg n)`, as `n <= f`) as follows:

- Build a (binary) [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) of the first `n` numbers in the file. (`O(n)`)
- For each remaining number in the file, compare it to the top element in the heap. If the new number is larger, pop the top element off and insert the new one. (`O(f)` times a `O(lg n)` operation).
- When done, the heap contains the `n` largest numbers in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your file looks something like this.

```
123 448 28239
1299 23729 71829
18283 75723 817
93993 1791 9
```

Using standard Unix tools, I'd do something like this.

```
$ tr " " "\n" < in.txt | sort -n -r | head -5
93993
75723
71829
28239
23729
```

Explanation:

- `tr` converts every space into a newline `\n`
- `sort -n -r` sorts the lines, which now contain one number each, numerically and revers
- `head -5` takes the top five of these sorted rows

Of course this doesn't answer your question for an algorithm.

**Edit:** A [Comparison of Internal Sorting Algorithms](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/comparison-of-internal-sorting-algorithms/) from 2008 gives some details about the algorithms used by various tools.

Comment: internal sorting tool can be used but for a file with a huge volume of  numbers would increase the time complexity by a significant amount
A single scan is an optimum solution

Comment: Do you know how `sort` is implemented? Besides, the *size* of the input will definitely not increase the *complexity* of the algorithm.

Comment: dunno how its internally done in UNIX... it should be the most efficient one.. not sure though

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array (say `topN[n]`) with length `n` and for every number in the file check if it's smaller then all `n` numbers in `topN`.
If not, replace this with the smallest in `topTen`.

This is a good solution if your `n` is not very big because the complexity of this algorithm is `O(n*k)` where `K` is the number of numbers in our file.

Actually complexity is `O(n*(k+1))` because every time you should add a new number to `topN` so that it stays sorted (it will help when adding the next number.)

**1.** Get next number

**2.** Search for it with a binary search in your `topN` array and find its
    place (largest item in array which is smaller then `nextNumber`)

**3.** Insert `nextNumber` to that location and shift all the next items in
    `topN` to the right.

**4.** The last item in `topN` will be removed from the array.

Comment: hmm i had thought of the soln... but here there is an overhead of searching for the entire array
heap sort would achieve a complexity of log n
maybe maintaining the array in sorted order and using a binary search would reduce the complexity

Comment: Hmm.. this implementation of the array is similar to maxheap..
Maxheap is likely to be more efficient though than this as there is no overhead for removing elements..we are just replacing them
Swaps will do in maxheaps unless we have to remove elements